Why can the Effective Federal Funds Rate (EFFR) be below the deposit rate at the Federal Reserve (FED)?
I have a question. From what I know, banks lend money to each other, and it’s done at the Effective Federal Funds Rate (EFFR). However, I’m wondering why this rate is lower than the Federal Reserve’s rate. I understand that it’s because banks can lend money to each other at a lower cost, but is there any other explanation for this phenomenon?

The FEDs interest rates form a corridor. The lower bound is IORB (Interest on reserve balances), the upper bound (theoretically) is the SRF (standing repo facility). Why fed funds can trade below IORB, is that in a regime of excess liquidity people are looking to park cash, not everyone has access to the IORB (ot ar least the rate payable by this facility), therefore people who do, usually charge an intermediation spread to park this cash and/or the particpants would rather earn IORB-x bps over night as opposed to 0 if left at the fed (not in IORB). Hence EFFR trades under the lower bound (as of now at least).

That is correct.  Specifically, Federal Agencies do not have access to the IORB because they are not depositary institutions.  So they lend in the Fed Funds market.  Some banks borrow from them in the Fed Funds market and redeposit at IORB to earn a spread.

Thanks, your answer cleared up my doubts. You mentioned something about the EFFR being below; what needs to happen for it to go above the lower bound?

With central bank balance sheets at unnaturally large levels due to quantitative easing, there are more central bank reserves in the system than there is demand for. In a competitive price setting, this would cause interest rates to fall. Therefore, the Fed (and other central banks) started paying interest on excess reserves to maintain control of interest rates.
For rates to go above the lower bound, quantitative tightening would need to be implemented to increase scarcity of reserves = higher prices = higher interest rates
